# Cast String to TimeSpan

Tags: vb.net, string

I tried to parse string to TimeSpan like the following :

```
    Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim timeCheckin As String = Format(dt, "HH:MM:FF")
    ts = TimeSpan.Parse(timeCheckin)
```

It threw error like this:

> System.OverflowException: The TimeSpan could not be parsed because at least one of the hours, minutes, or seconds components is outside its valid range.

Can anyone give me a suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter for [`TimeSpan.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(VS.71).aspx) must be in format `hh:mm:ss`, not `hh:mm:ff`

The format is `[ws][-][d.]hh:mm:ss[.ff][ws]`

`hh:mm:ss` are required, the others are optional

```
Dim timeCheckin As String = Format(dt, "HH:mm:ss")
ts = TimeSpan.Parse(timeCheckin)
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint after the TimeSpan.Parse and investigate the ts variable. It has all properties - Minutes, Hours and etc... You will find out if the ts has correct value

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. Thank you.

Comment: `MM` is months. You need lowercase `mm` for minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really trying to parse [hours, months and fractions of seconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73ctwf33.aspx)?

Your format string should probably be something like `HH:mm:ss` instead.