# How to calculate only hours and minute diffrenece without using datetime control?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, vb.net-2010, timespan

I am working on windows, vb.net application.

I want to calculate the time difference or total time between two Times.

I have used hour, minute and AM/PM combo boxes instead of the datetime control.

You can understand by watching the images below.

[image]

Now, As you can see, I want to calculate the total Batch time from these two time.

In below scenario there is 8 hours. but I want to build the logic for it...
Any one come across this kind of problem ? Is there any easy to to do it ?

(Date is doesn't matter here, So I didn't take the datetime controller.)

Comment: Take the string inputs and parse them to a TimeSpan, then do the calculation. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874490/cast-string-to-timespan

Comment: Did you realise the DateTimePicker can be used to enter just times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the ParseExact method to parse the values into a DateTime (or Timespan) variable. Example here shows DateTime as the custom string format is a little easier to understand:

```
    Dim startBatch = DateTime.ParseExact("8:00 AM", "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    Dim endBatch = DateTime.ParseExact("4:00 PM", "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    Dim diff = endBatch.Subtract(startBatch)
    MessageBox.Show("Difference is: " & diff.ToString)
```