# How can I pass only the time using RadTimePicker in vb.net?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, dictionary, telerik, datetimepicker

I am using a RadTimePicker which I want to be able to pass the time only to the database as it passes a date even when you don't set one.

**How I want to pass it to the database:**

10:30

**How I want it to be stored in the database:**

10:30

**Error I received in Visual Studio:**

"Cannot convert String to TimeSpan"

This was because of the RadTimePicker I am using automatically passes a date even if there isn't one set, so it passes 01/01/0001 00:00:00 and I don't need or want the date part.

Because I couldn't get it working I decided to do a workaround using varchar but then I was shown how to properly set it up using time datatype.

**I used this for the conversion to fix my error I got the 1st time**

[Cast String to TimeSpan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874490/cast-string-to-timespan)

The solution for that is shown below.

Answer (score -1):

I have now corrected my answer to replicate the 'correct' way of storing time.

**Input Fields:**

[image: Input Fields]

**How it's stored in the database:**

[image: Stored values]

**Data Types in the 'Update DB stored procedure' and the database table:**

[image: Data Types]

**Declaring global Date Variables**

[image: Global date variables]

**How to Pass only the time:**

[image: Getting the time part of the data]

**Passing Data using Dictionary**

[image: Dictionary values]

Hope this helps!

Comment: You already asked this question previously and someone told you what data type to use and you're not using it. If you refuse advice when it's provided, what's the point?

Comment: I tried their method and it didn't work for me - hence why I've done it this way...

Comment: Then you did it wrong. You should be using the correct data type and that is definitely not `varchar` for time. Start with the right data type in the database and go from there. To save data to that data type in SQL Server you need a `TimeSpan` so the actual question you should be asking is how to get a `TimeSpan` from your control. I don;t use that control at all but, based on the name, I would assume that it already provides a `TimeSpan` or, if not, a `DateTime`. A `DateTime` has a property to get a `TimeSpan` from. You created the problem in the first place with your incorrect data types.

Comment: If that `Value` property you're using is type `DateTime`, which my research indicates is the case, then you can get a `TimeSpan` from its `TimeOfDay` property, which your research should have told you was the case. You can then save that value to your database column if it's the correct data type, which you have been provided in another thread.

Comment: I had an issue with the time-span which I couldn't figure out as I've not used this control before. While I appreciate the help, there are many different solutions available - I don't feel that what I did was wrong, simply just another solution. Now you've explained it to me though, I have managed to get it working the 'correct' way. So I will amend my answer to replicate this. Also with regards to your first response, advice doesn't have to be taken as it is just advice :D Thanks for the help! Have a nice day!

Comment: If you used a text data type to store time data then what you did was wrong. The fact that you can get the desired end result does not make something right. It's just not as wrong as some of the alternatives.